# code not following the procedure

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, uart, attiny

I am currently working with ATTiny1634, executing the following code

After executing break statement the program is not exiting from the inner while loop to outer while loop; instead, it jumps to main function.

To test, I removed all the USART functions `uart_init`, `writecommand`, `transmit`, after removing all these function code is working perfectly.

The code works with ATMega16A, but getting problem in ATTiny1634. Why?

```
int main()
{   
    DDRC=1<<DDRC0;
    DDRA|= 1<<PORTA3;
    uart_init();
    sei();  
    writecommand("AT");

    writecommand("ATE0");
while (1)

  {
    int8_t t;
    PORTA=1<<PORTA3;
    // controller sleep mode
        if(MCUSR & (1<<WDRF))
        {
            MCUSR&= ~(1<<WDRF);
            WDTCSR|= 1<<WDE;
            WDTCSR= 0x00;
        }
        PORTA=0<<PORTA3;
        set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN); // sleep mode selected
            //PRR=0X75;
            wdt_reset();
            WDTCSR |= 1<<WDE;           
            WDTCSR |= (1<<WDIE|1<<WDP3 |1<<WDP0); // ENABLE WATCH DOG TIMER INTERRUPT WITH 8S TIME OUT          
        sleep_enable();  //set SE bit   
        sei();  
        sleep_cpu(); //sleep mode activated

      while (1)
        {
         if(count >=2) // 80S DELAY
           {
            count=0;
            sleep_disable();   // SE bit reset
            WDTCSR|=0<<WDE|0<<WDIE; // disable watch dog timer
            transmit("AT+CFUN=1\r\n");
            _delay_ms(2000);            
            clearbuffer(buff);
            clearbuffer(temp_buff);
            _delay_ms(2000);
            break;
           }
         else
          {
            WDTCSR|=1<<WDIE;
            sleep_cpu();
          }         
        }

    }    

}
```

The code for `writecommand`:
    void writecommand(char *q)
    {

```
    char str[3]="OK";
    char str1[50];
    do
    {
        clearbuffer(str1);
        strcpy(str1,q);

        i=0;
        _delay_ms(10);
        clearbuffer(buff);
        clearbuffer(temp_buff);
        transmit(str1);
        transmit("\r\n");
        _delay_ms(200);
        for(j=10;j>0;j--)
        _delay_ms(10);
        logic();   // my me
        clearbuffer(buff);        

    }while(strcmp(str3,str)!=0);
```

I am using the 8 MHz internal osc and the baud rate in USART is 9600. Other functions are:

```
void uart_init()
{
    UCSR0B=(1<<TXEN0)|(1<<RXEN0)|(1<<RXCIE0); //transmitter enable,receiver enable,receive complete interrupt enable
    UCSR0C=(1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00);//8 bit data bits  
    UBRR0L=51; // baud rate 9600
}
void uart_send(unsigned char ch)
{
    while(!(UCSR0A &(1<<UDRE0)));
    UDR0=ch;
}
void transmit(char *p)
{
    i=0;
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        uart_send(*p);
        p++; 
    }
}
void clearbuffer(char *p)
{
    while(*p!=0)
    {
        *p=' ';
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're playing with the watchdog here, I'm assuming your UART code either has a bug or is too slow, so you get a reset. Debugging your code is both impossible (it's not complete) and something I wouldn't consider doing anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you change from one processor to another, ***EVERY*** reference to a peripheral needs to be re-examined. Your code is a *perfect* example - it is full of Watchdog-specific code, and any change could cause the new processor to behave strangely.

Do you know what a Watchdog timer is? It is inside the controller, and its ***sole*** purpose is to **reset** the microcontroller back to the beginning of `main()`. That is all it does, and the *only* thing that can stop it is if the code "pats" the Watchdog before it times out. The idea is that you carefully structure your program so that it "pats" the Watchdog every so often - if it doesn't, then the code is bad and the microcontroller resets.

The code given even has a bug inside it:

```
    WDTCSR|= 1<<WDE;
    WDTCSR= 0x00;
```

This code carefully sets up bits inside the "**W**atch**D**og **T**imer **C**ontrol/**S**tatus **R**egister (`WDTCSR`)" - then zeroes it. Ummm... what?

In short, it is difficult to take existing code for one processor and simply execute it on a different one and expect it to work. Until you do, I would recommend that you comment out ***ALL*** code that references the Watchdog, until you get the rest of your code working.

Comment: sir i instead of using this command  `WDTCSR|=0<<WDE|0<<WDIE;`

Comment: That is even worse. It does absolutely nothing: you are `OR`ing `0` into a variable, which leaves... exactly the same value. If you want to zero those variables, you need to instead do `WDTCSR &= ~(0<<WDE|0<<WDIE);` - or not set them in the first place...

Comment: sir i instead of using this command  `WDTCSR|=0<<WDE|0<<WDIE;` i used `wdt_disable` to disable the wdt.now it not jumping to main function. it is just exiting the inner while loop.(i also omit the bug you talked about) The reason m not getting because in data sheet what i read if we set WDE bit && WDIE bit of WDTCSR to 0(zero),the wdt will stop and no action at the time of timeout.but when i used the predefined command it works why?

Comment: Whoops! I wasn't thinking. My line should have been `WDTCSR &= ~(1<<WDE|1<<WDIE);`

Comment: The wdt is getting disable correctly with `wdt_disable` command.i even tried both the line u have told, still was jumping to main function.i really wanna knw the reason why this was happening.

Comment: Once the `WDE` bit is turned on, it is ***very*** difficult to turn it off again (by design) - read your microprocessor manual to find out how. Naïvely turning off the bit won't do it.`wdt_disable()` is obviously doing the correct "secret magic" to do the right thing - so if you never turn it on, you won't have the problem.

Comment: @pranjalkhanduri In 99.9% of all applications, it doesn't make any sense to programmatically disable the watchdog. Instead, if you don't want to use it, never enable it. Professional programmers use debug build vs release build.